# No trae cuerpo del correo garethp/php-ews de PHP - EWS

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de realizar la conexion con la libreria garethp/php-ews de PHP, pero cuando intento obtener el cuerpo del correo no me trae nada.

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI;

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword('server', 'username', 'password');

$items = $api->getMailItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item instanceof Type\MessageType) {
        $emailId = $item->getItemId()->getId();
        $subject = $item->getSubject();
        echo "EmailId: " . $emailId . "<br>";
        echo "Subject: " . $subject . "<br>";
        $body = $item->getBody();
        echo "Body: " . $body . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Cuando traigo el asunto y el Id correo lo trae bien, la cosa es solo con el cuerpo del correo, no me trae ni muestra nada.

Comment: La verdad no utilice nunca esta libreria, pero por los ejemplos pareciera que primero tenes que hacer `$mailItem = $api->getItem($item->getItemId());` y después `$mailItem->getBody();`